# javascript issue body style

Tags: javascript

Here's my code, any idea why it's not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

windows.onload = function() {

function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = ('red');
}
};


</script>
```

Comment: Is that "jQuery" in your title ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without jquery, you can do that :

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
};
```

In your code you declared a function inside the callback you give to onload but you didn't call it.

Comment: Nope. I know how to do it with jQuery. I want to do it WITHOUT it. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Wow it works. Funny thing I've tried this. Must've overlooked something :D

Comment: @Lucenzo you had `windowS.onload` instead of `window.onload`

Comment: Look at the source code, around line 6555 in the current release. jQuery essentially does what you've written in your question but also does some checks to ensure cross browser compatibility which may be applicable to some styles and values.  It also provides support for css hooks. So while the end result in this case is the same jQuery offers a lot more features, as you'd expect.

Comment: `window.onload` and `$(document).ready` are NOT the same thing. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring an anonymous function but never executing it. Also, `windows.onload` is probably not what you meant.

What were you expecting to happen?

If you're trying to change the background color when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/8hQyu/

Simulating a `document.ready` callback without jQuery is not really a trivial task, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).

As far as the background color goes, this works fine:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = ('red');
```

Comment: I've explained in the comment above, I know how to do it with jQuery. I was trying to do it without jquery.